# Iterating over network API call using Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

So I'm using a custom google search API to get an image URL for each name parameter in my dataset.

I'd like to iterate over each name in the dataset as a query parameter in an API call to Retrofit2.

```
public interface GoogleImageAPI {
    @GET("v1?key=MyAPIKEY&cx=MyCustomSearchID&searchType=image&fileType=jpg&imgSize=large&alt=json")
    Observable<Photos> loadPhotos(@Query("q") String artistQuery);
}
```

So far I've built the Retrofit adapter and API instance to return an Observable:

```
public Observable<Photos> getPhotosObservable(String artistName){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/")
            .build();
    GoogleImageAPI googleImageAPI = retrofit.create(GoogleImageAPI.class);
    return googleImageAPI.loadPhotos(artistName.replace(" ","+"));
}
```

I have a getPhotos(String name) method that creates an observable and subscribes to it. I am able to run this method with a test parameter, i.e.getPhotos("rocket") and it returns a Photos object which contains a List of the top 10 google photo search results for "rocket"

```
public void getPhotos(String artistName){
    Observable<Photos> photosObservable = mDataManager.getPhotosObservable(artistName);
    Subscription subscription = photosObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<Photos>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                if(e instanceof HttpException){
                    HttpException response = (HttpException)e;
                    Log.i(TAG,"bad response: "+response.code());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Photos photos) {
                Photos mPhotos = photos;
                Log.i(TAG,"size: "+mPhotos);
            }
        });
}
```

Is there a safe/correct way of iterating over this method, consequently calling the API 100's of times without running out of memory or creating 100's of observables?

For example, could I do something like this? It seems very resource intensive:

```
for(String name : artistNames){
    googleImageAPI.loadPhotos(name.replace(" ","+"))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<Github>() {
        @Override
        public final void onCompleted() {
            // do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public final void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.e("GithubDemo", e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public final void onNext(Github response) {
            mCardAdapter.addData(response);
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit (Working example) resulting in a combined list of Photo objects:**

```
public void getPhotos(){
    mDataManager.getArtists()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(new Action1<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void call(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                LinkedHashMap<Integer,Artist> artistMap = presentArtists(jsonArray);
                Collection<Artist> artists = artistMap.values();
                Observable.from(artists)
                   .map(new Func1<Artist, String>() {
                       @Override
                       public String call(Artist artist) {
                           String artistName;
                           if(artist.getName().contains("(")){
                               artistName = artist.getName().substring(0,artist.getName().indexOf("(")-2).replace(" ","+");
                           }else {
                               artistName = artist.getName().replace(" ", "+");
                           }
                           return artistName;
                       }
                   })
                    .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<Photos>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Observable<Photos> call(String artistName) {
                           return mDataManager.getPhotosObservable(artistName);
                        }
                    })
                    .toList()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Photos>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {}

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(List<Photos> objects) {
                            mDataManager.savePhotos(objects);
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
    Observable.from(artistNames)
            .map(name -> name.replace(" ", "+"))
            .flatMap(name -> googleImageAPI.loadPhotos(name))
            .toList()
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Github>>() {
                @Override
                public final void onCompleted() {
                    // do nothing
                }

                @Override
                public final void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e("GithubDemo", e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public final void onNext(List<Github> response) {
                    mCardAdapter.addAll(response);
                }
            })
```

Create an `Observable` from the `List`. Use the `map` operator to replace spaces with pluses. Use `flatMap` to call the API. Use `toList` to create a list of all the responses. Then you can add ALL the responses with `addAll` to the adapter.

Comment: This is excellent, thanks. I included a working solution (without lambdas) appended to my question. It's easy to see now, how lambdas make the code a lot cleaner and easier to read, but that's a lesson for another day.

Comment: @Futureproof my pleasure. Also take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html for URL encoding strings.

Comment: Even better! And to think I almost created a utility class to handle all the different URL variations. Thanks again.